# Aarch64 Frame pointer

Tags: arm, arm64

I saw this code on page 120 of ArmV8 Programmer's Guide:

```
foo//
SUB SP, SP, #0x30 
STR W0, [SP, #0x2C] 
STR W1, [SP, #0x28] 
STR D0, [SP, #0x20] 
STR D1, [SP, #0x18] 
LDR W0, [SP, #0x2C] 
STR W0, [SP, #0] 
LDR W0, [SP, #0x28] 
STR W0, [SP, #4] 
LDR W0, [SP, #0x20] 
STR W0, [SP, #8] 
LDR W0, [SP, #0x18] 
STR W0, [SP, #10] 
LDR X9, [SP, #0x0] 
STR X9, [X8, #0] 
LDR X9, [SP, #8] 
STR X9, [X8, #8] 
LDR X9, [SP, #0x10] 
STR X9, [X8, #0x10] 
ADD SP, SP, #0x30 
RET

bar//
STP X29, X30, [SP, #0x10]! 
MOV X29, SP
SUB SP, SP, #0x20
ADD X8, SP, #8
MOV W0, WZR
ORR W1, WZR, #1
FMOV D0, #1.00000000
FMOV D1, #2.00000000
BL foo:
ADRP X8, {PC}, 0x78
ADD X8, X8, #0
LDR X9, [SP, #8]
STR X9, [X8, #0]
LDR X9, [SP, #0x10]
STR X9, [X8, #8]
LDR X9, [SP, #0x18]
STR X9, [X8, #0x10]
MOV SP, X29
LDP X20, X30, [SP], #0x10
RET
```

My question is regarding to following instruction at the end of bar routine:

```
LDP X20, X30, [SP], #0x10
```

LDP is for loading pair of registers from stack and restriction for this instruction will not allow loading to registers at that distance.

First, why this line can be valid ?
Second, why FP is loaded into x20 ? Isn't it supposed to load into x29 ?

From ARM Procedure call standard :

> Each frame shall link to the frame of its caller by means of a frame record of two 64-bit values on the stack

Of course it also mentions cases which these requirements are not mandatory, but in this case FP seems to be not valid because it is pointing to sp - 0x10 which which has fp and lr .

Comment: I assume the "manual" in question is the [ARMv8-A Programmer's Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/index.html). It's not clear what you mean by "restriction for this instruction will not allow loading to registers at that distance" - what restriction do you mean? As for what seems to be a pretty straightforward typo, feel free to report it as per the "feedback on this book" section in the preface.

Comment: That's correct, i edited the post, thanks. By restriction i mean for example stp x20,x24, [sp, -16]! Is invalid, is that also the case with ldp ?

Comment: That example is only invalid in the sense that writing below SP is a violation of the ABI. If you're not following the ABI (e.g. in some self-contained assembly code which doesn't need to be compatible with debuggers/stack unwinding code/etc.) there's nothing wrong with it in ISA terms. Remember that A64 `ldp`/`stp` differ from A32 `ldrd`/`strd` in that [they can use any two target registers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25195861/3156750)

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for, now its clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Notlikethat i have a off topic question. Is mov sp, x0 and mov lr, x2 valid in aarch64 ?

Comment: Note that strictly there's no such thing as `lr` in the A64 assembly language, although it's possible some assemblers might choose to allow it as an alias for `x30`. Handy instruction set reference [over that way](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801c/pge1427897679276.html) :P